# Hide HTML scrollbar temporarily

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a chat window (just an <ol>) which is scrollable using `overflow:auto`. Every time a new message arrives, I use `ol.scrollTop = ol.scrollHeight` to make the list scroll to the bottom, ensuring the new message is always visible.

On OSX at least, this triggers the scrollbar to appear and shortly after disappear again. I want to keep the standard scrollbar behaviour *except* in this case.

I have tried `::-webkit-scrollbar` to hide the scrollbar temporarily, but a) I can't seem to show it again afterwards and b) obviously this won't work in other browsers anyway.

Any ideas how to prevent the scrollbar appearing during this one transition?

Comment: make the width of the scrollable element slightly greater (so the scrolbar will be hiden by container). Assuming your html structure can be used this way

Comment: Bit confused here. With `overflow` set to `scroll`, the scrollbar will *always* be present regardless of whether or not the element can be scrolled. Yet you say, while scrolling with JavaScript it appears and then disappears again, implying you actually have `overflow` set to `hidden`. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @Shaggy Apologies, have fixed to say `overflow:auto`.

Comment: Again, though, if it can be scrolled and `overflow` is set to `auto`, the scroll bar will always be present. Or do you mean to say there are instances when there is not enough content in the `ol` to be scrolled but your scroll function fires anyway and *this* is when the scrollbar is flickering? If that's the case then maybe include a conditional in you JavaScript to check if the `ol` can be scrolled before trying to do so.

Comment: @Shaggy On OSX, though, the OS decides when to show the scrollbar even when using `auto` or `scroll`. I'm actually OK with the scrollbar being present, its just when OSX uses its internal logic to hide / show the flicker is disconcerting. I've applied a terrible hack that shifts the scrollbar off-screen and back again after a delay, but its pretty awful.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to, using JavaScript, add a class to your `ol` that overwrites the `overflow` property and then, by adding a `scroll` event listener, remove that class again.

I threw this together *very* quickly to demonstrate. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Mac to test it so you may need to set a timeout within the event listener for removing the class.

```js
var list=document.getElementById("list");
setTimeout(down,2000);

list.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    list.classList.remove("noscroll");
},0)

function down(){
    list.classList.add("noscroll");
    list.scrollTop=list.scrollHeight;
    setTimeout(up,2000);
};

function up(){
    list.classList.add("noscroll");
    list.scrollTop=0;
    setTimeout(down,2000);
};
```

```css
#list{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
 width:200px;
}
#list.noscroll{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
```